# How to use Google map poly-line API by passing array of coordinates dynamically?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polyline

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDCqX.jpg)
I am new to google api. Please help me to use Google map poly-line API by passing array of coordinates dynamically?

Comment: Pictures of code are not useful, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**make array of latlng and then use that array path in polyline obj**

```
var latlngArray = [[lat,lng],[lat,lng],[lat,lng],[lat,lng]];
var patharray = [];
for (var i = 0;i<latlngArray .length ;i++){
patharray.push(new google.maps.LatLng(latlngArray[i][0],latlngArray[i][1]));
}
var tourplan = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path : patharray ,
        strokeColor : "#0000FF",
        strokeOpacity : 0.6,
        strokeWeight : 2,
 });
tourplan.setMap(map)
```

Comment: Thanks Akshay. I want to pass the coordinates from oracle database in Java Dynamic web project. Can you please give me a rough idea how to get it done.